# Troubleshooting sound on Asus Rog Zephyrus i7 running Debian 12

Tags: audio, debian, debian-bookworm

I recently bought a new laptop (Asus Rog Zephyrus i7) and I installed Debian 12 onto it. Everything is fine except the sound.

I can hear the sound but it's like it's not fully using the speaker, just a really high sound with no base which is hard to hear with no bass.

I have made some attempts to fix it by trying various suggestions online to no avail. Such as this advice in the [Debian user forums](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=155514).

I've tried some suggested ideas which affected audiopulse but I have no idea what I'm doing.

Here is the output from `sudo hwinfo --short`:

```
cpu:                                                            
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 700 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 400 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 696 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 984 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 845 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 400 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 550 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 766 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 825 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 400 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 938 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 400 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 666 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 825 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 400 MHz
                       13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13620H, 775 MHz
keyboard:
  /dev/input/mice      ASUSTek N-KEY Device
  /dev/input/event0    AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      ASUF1205:00 2808:0106 Mouse
  /dev/input/mice      ASUF1205:00 2808:0106 Touchpad
monitor:
                       NE160WUM-NX2
graphics card:
                       nVidia VGA compatible controller
                       Intel VGA compatible controller
sound:
                       Intel Audio device
                       nVidia Audio device
storage:
                       Intel RAID bus controller
                       Sandisk Non-Volatile memory controller
network:
  wlo1                 Intel WLAN controller
  enp57s0              Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
network interface:
  wlo1                 Ethernet network interface
  enp57s0              Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
disk:
  /dev/nvme0n1         Sandisk Disk
partition:
  /dev/nvme0n1p1       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p2       Partition
  /dev/nvme0n1p3       Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel USB Controller
                       Intel USB Controller
                       Intel USB Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel ISA bridge
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel Host bridge
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel PCI bridge
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
bluetooth:
                       Intel Bluetooth Device
unknown:
                       FPU
                       DMA controller
                       PIC
                       Keyboard controller
                       PS/2 Controller
                       Intel System peripheral
                       Genesys Logic GL9755 SD Host Controller
                       Intel Serial bus controller
                       Intel System peripheral
                       Intel Signal processing controller
                       Intel Communication controller
                       Intel Serial bus controller
                       Intel Serial bus controller
                       Intel Communication controller
                       Intel Serial bus controller
                       Intel RAM memory
                       Intel SMBus
                       Quanta USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
```

Here is the output of `sudo lspci -k | grep -A 4 Audio`:

```
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
--
0000:01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
0000:38:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc GL9755 SD Host Controller (rev 01)
anonymous@debian:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0x622f280000 irq 204
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0x60080000 irq 17
```

Here is the output of `sudo dmesg | grep "snd\|sof\|intel\|firmware"`:

```
[    0.020206] software IO TLB: area num 16.
[    0.763672] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
[    0.763673] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0x0000000021eeb000-0x0000000025eeb000] (64MB)
[    0.970543] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    0.971758] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    1.008847] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Corporation UEFI CA 2011: 13adbf4309bd82709c8cd54f316ed522988a1bd4'
[    1.008863] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'Microsoft Windows Production PCA 2011: a92902398e16c49778cd90f99e4f9ae17c55af53'
[    1.288688] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.310480] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.330555] intel-lpss 0000:00:1e.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.346487] intel-lpss 0000:00:1e.2: enabling device (0004 -> 0006)
[    1.711488] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_16.bin
[    1.712914] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/adlp_dmc_ver2_16.bin (v2.16)
[    1.724607] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.bin
[    1.724818] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin
[    1.838666] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.bin version 70.5.1
[    1.838669] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3
[    3.066555] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Skipping intel_backlight registration
[    8.999023] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    9.129839] intel_rapl_msr: PL4 support detected.
[    9.130971] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    9.130976] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    9.130979] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    9.130982] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    9.245884] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[    9.246276] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[    9.254155] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    9.284359] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode
[    9.285127] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    9.285178] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    9.285266] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    9.285310] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    9.310560] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    9.310756] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    9.310965] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    9.310970] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    9.393220] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC285: line_outs=2 (0x14/0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    9.393233] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    9.393238] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    9.393242] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    9.393245] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[    9.393248] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x13
[    9.393250] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x19
[    9.393253] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x1b
[    9.393255] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    9.419555] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    9.421021] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[    9.421027] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0040-0041.sfi
[    9.599893] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
[   10.223925] r8169 0000:39:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw
[   10.912847] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   10.929892] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
[   10.929897] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
```

Here is the output of `sudo dmidecode -t system`:

```
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.5.0 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: ROG Zephyrus G16 GU603VV_GU603VV
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    UUID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: ROG Zephyrus G16

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 12, 5 bytes
System Configuration Options
    Option 1: Default string

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 32, 20 bytes
System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected`
```